# Trying to position a box div within another box div

Tags: html, css

i hope you can give me a hand with this one, I'm trying to put a div within a div but one keeps pulling the other down.

i'll paste some images:

This is what i'm trying to acomplish...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABQZC.jpg)

And this is what I get...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4LAZ.jpg)

An a brief explanation:

I need this "faded" box to be in the center on the page, then, I need this "NEW WAVE" text to be within said box, one problem I have is that if I put them in the same div, the text inherit the "faded" condition, but if I put them in different divs, the "faded" box pushes the div of the text down. I think I've tried the usual ways to fix this but nothing happens, yet, I'm just starting with HTML and CSS so clearly I'm missing something.

Now i'll leave the HTML and the CSS:

HTML:

```
<div class="dimmed">
            <div class="dim-back"></div>
            <div class="new-wave">
              <h2>NEW WAVE</h2>
            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS (for this one i'll post an image):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbcCI.jpg)

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the css?

Comment: Please post the CSS.. A picture does not help those that wish to copy the code to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. What you have to do now is to change background colors, dimensions and other basic css to style is as you want. I suppose this is what you tried to achieve - box within a box with a title in the middle.

```css
.dimmed{width:500px;height:300px;background:blue;
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:center}

.dim-back{width:300px;height:150px;background:red;
        border:5px white solid;
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:center}
```

```html
<div class="dimmed">
 <div class="dim-back">
  <div class="new-wave"><h2>NEW WAVE</h2></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Instead of background:blue use background:rgba(0,0,0,.3) and the last value (.3) is opacity (called alpha). You don't need a background for red box. This way it will look exactly as you want.

**UPDATE:**
Same result can be achieved after removing some `<div>`. Check this solution. there is nothing easiest.

```css
.dimmed{width:500px;height:300px;
        background:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:center}
h2{width:300px;height:150px;
        border:5px white solid;
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:center}
```

```html
<div class="dimmed">
 <h2>NEW WAVE</h2>
</div>
```

You can use padding for`<h2>` tags instead of dimensions. In that case padding and border is the only thing you need. It depends on what you put in h2 tags (block image or text).

Comment: Instead of background:blue use background:rgba(0,0,0,.3) and the last value (.3) is opacity. You don't need a background for red box. This way it will look exactly as you want.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you very much, now I got to figure out how to make the h2 solid (because it's inheriting the opacity from the .dim-back). Once again, thank you!

Comment: Dont use opacity. Use background:rgba(0,0,0,.3) where last digit .3 in the example is background opacity. This is not causing your h2 to inherit opacity.

Comment: Wow!! It worked, if you don't mind, could you explain to to me why it worked that way and not the other way around, because for me is basically the same (except that it's not, clearly). Thank you!

Comment: css opacity aplies opacity to all children in a parent. If you use background rgba you make a background with rgb colors and alpha channel (opacity).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, Since you haven't shown your CSS yet.

The primary mistakes which I usually end up doing when using Bootstrap was with my starting and closing of div tags

You current structure happens to be like this.

```
<div class="dimmed">
            <div class="dim-back"></div>
            <div class="new-wave">
              <h2>NEW WAVE</h2>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Try Nesting your div tags like this

```
<div class="dimmed">
            <div class="dim-back">
            <div class="new-wave">
              <h2>NEW WAVE</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```